# What are the most recited verses during Jewish prayer?

Tags: tefilla, tanach, quotations

What are the top three most recited/used verses/supplications (from or not from Torah) in Jewish prayers? Not asking about the single most used one only.

I think, if a passage or a sentence is repeated again and again in prayers, it reflects the relation between G_d and man according to Judaism. That's why I am asking.

Please provide English translations also. This question is from a non-Jew.

Comment: *Divrei Hayamim A* [16:35](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/קטגוריה:דברי_הימים_א_טז_לה) is a big one, especially if you use [*nusach S'farad*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nusach_Sefard).

Comment: Gulshan, unfortunately I think this is not constructive. As it currently stands, anyway. What exactly do you mean "[n]ot ... the single most used one only"? How many do you want? Are you asking for us to list all of our prayers/verses/supplications and rank them in order of most to least used?

Comment: What @SethJ said. Moreover, since you're asking also about those not from the Torah, it's unclear how long a verse/supplication you seek. (For example, would "Blessed art thou" suffice?)

Comment: @SethJ and msh210 Would my question be opened if I ask for the single most Torah verse only? Actually I do not know much, thus the confusion.

Comment: @Gulshan, maybe if you explain more about what you are interested in using the information for, either in a comment here or in the question, people can help you sharpen the question such that it can garner answers that will be helpful.

Comment: @IsaacMoses For example, Muslims say "Sura Fatiha" from quran http://quran.com/1 multiples times in each of the 5 daily prayers they offer. This is the most recited verse of their holy book, Quran. I was asking about something similar to Judaism.

Comment: IMO if the question were edited so it asked for the one Tanach verse, or for the one Pentateuch verse, or both, most repeated in prayers, that'd definitely be reopenable. What @IsaacMoses said would still hold, though.

Comment: @Gulshan, So it sounds like you're interested in discovering if there is a particular passage (looks like on paragraph, or at least sentence, scale) that's repeated many times throughout Jewish prayer. Can you say more about why you're interested in knowing this? Is it so that you'll have a sense of what Jews must be thinking about the most, if they repeat it the most?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I think, if a passage or a sentence is repeated again and again in prayers, it describes the relation between G_d and man. That's why I am asking. But I am more interested about a passage or sentence rather than the relation in general.

Comment: @msh210, I think it's OK to ask for more than one, though I remain uneasy with the open-endedness of just asking for an innumerate "the most ... [plural]." Should we put a numeric cap on this (e.g. "top five")?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I am ok with even just one. Top three will suffice I think.

Comment: I know Gulshan might not know about this, but there are a number of different rites when it comes to parts of the prayer, as well as looser and tighter ways to define what's included in 'prayer'. @All Should this be clarified somewhat before reopening, to ensure Gulshan gets the type of response he seeks?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't think it makes sense to try to add too much precision. The one clarification I can think of as being worth considering would be to focus the question, a priori, on passages whose repetition specifically does indicate something about our relationship with God, as opposed to just leaving that concept as part of the motivation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure. The [amidah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amidah) might be the most recited and repeated prayer during the services on any day.